# How to modify icon of matplotlib navigation

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have been able to delete/disable different matplotlib navigation toolbar buttons with the following code:

```
canvasplt_matplotlib_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(
    self.canvasplt, self
)

matplotlib_toolbar_with_removed_icons = self.canvasplt.toolbar
unwanted_buttons = ["Back", "Forward", "Customize", "Subplots", "Save"]
for x in matplotlib_toolbar_with_removed_icons.actions():
    if x.text() in unwanted_buttons:
        matplotlib_toolbar_with_removed_icons.removeAction(x)
```

Now I would like to change the icon design of the remaining icons, such as home, pan and zoom that it fits to the genereal GUI design.

How can I modify these icons with my own .ico files?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is similar to removing the QAction since you must iterate to obtain the respective QAction and replace the icon using the setIcon method:

```
unwanted_buttons = ["Back", "Forward", "Customize", "Subplots", "Save"]

icons_buttons = {
    "Home": QtGui.QIcon("/path/of/home.png"),
    "Pan": QtGui.QIcon("/path/of/pan.png"),
    "Zoom": QtGui.QIcon("/path/of/zoom.png"),
}
for action in matplotlib_toolbar_with_removed_icons.actions():
    if action.text() in unwanted_buttons:
        matplotlib_toolbar_with_removed_icons.removeAction(action)
    if action.text() in icons_buttons:
        action.setIcon(icons_buttons.get(action.text(), QtGui.QIcon()))
```